# Why doesn't emplace/_front/_back return a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, return-value

When using `std::vector`s, `std::list`s (or other STL containers), I happen to often write this, for code shortness (rather than putting explicit `vec[index]` every time) and memory allocation efficiency (avoiding a copy/move), and I suppose I'm not the only one to do such:

```
std::vector<A> vec;
vec.emplace_back();
A &element = vec[vec.size()-1];
element.prop = "value";
```

**Why doesn't STL containers' `emplace`, `emplace_back` and `emplace_front` methods return a `T&`?** It would allow one to write simply this rather than using a shady `vec.size()-1`:

```
std::vector<A> vec;
A &element = vec.emplace_back();
element.prop = "value";
```

Comment: There's `vector::back()`...

Comment: @T.C. True, but I never think of it... Anyway, the same question applies.

Comment: I think the most likely rationale for `emplace_back` having a `void` return type is symmetry with the other value insertion methods, such as `push_back`. It wouldn't be too difficult to write a utility function that does the `emplace_back` and returns the reference you are looking for.

Comment: @Niall: Which begs the question why those don't return a reference either.

Comment: @Deduplicator. Good question, no idea. Legacy (and compatibility) I suppose; maybe it wasn't ever thought of.

Comment: Someone else is probably also wondering why you can't do: `vec.emplace_back().emplace_back()`

Comment: I really don't know why they should. Nothing about their name tells me that they should return a value. And it doesn't buy you anything efficiency-wise.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/ - this one returns iterator, but it needs an iterator argument too

Comment: Why not add a constructor signature to `A` that allows you to set the value of `prop` at construction?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: For the same reason `new` returns a pointer to an object.  :P  You just caused the creation of an object; you shouldn't have to then do additional work to get at what you just made.  Particularly considering that the container already knows exactly where that object is, and any method of finding it yourself only works if you do it right when you've added the object.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This has been fixed in [C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).
Your example

```
std::vector<A> vec;
A &element = vec.emplace_back();
element.prop = "value";
```

is valid C++17 code.

Comment: Why a reference rather than an iterator?

Comment: @akim Because in the case of a `std::vector`(-like) container, `emplace_font/back()` would always return `front()`/`back()`, and returning an iterator would require additional indirection to access the emplaced object.

Comment: "fixed" is in the eye of the beholder, assuming we thought the lack was a bug and not a feature ;-) but I guess this should be innocuous enough, as it should be trivial to see that the reference is unused and optimise it away. +1 for the info anyway.

Answer (score 11):

You have member methods to access those objects, since you *know* where they have been inserted. Namely `front()` and `back()`.

Some other functions (e.g. `map::insert`) would return an iterator because *you don't know how to access the inserted element in constant time*. In the case of `emplace`, you do know.

Another reason for not returning anything might be performance (most of the time you would not use the returned value). And in C++ , you pay for what you use.

Comment: The chance of the compiler optimizing an `emplace_back` where the return value isn't used are high (since the chance of most of the function being inlined are high and the compiler can simply drop the dead code associated with the return). On the other hand, the chance of the compiler optimizing an `emplace_back()` followed by a `back()` are quite low since it would need to optimize across two different functions and "see into" the dynamically allocated to storage and be able to track the value of the `size` member and see than the just-inserted element is accessed.

Comment: This is further complicated by the fact that the `emplace` flow has a usually-not-lined "grow the vector" slow path, which pretty much means the chance of an optimization across those two functions is close to zero, even if the grow path doesn't usually occur.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need it.  Write this:

```
template<class C, class...Args>
auto emplace_back(C& c, Args&&...args)->decltype(c.back()){
  c.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return c.back();
}
```

and you have the semantics you want without having to modify the container interface.

Just:

```
emplace_back(vec).prop = "foo";
```

Answer (score 7):

Two arguments for choosing this signature:

- API symmetry. These APIs are symmetric with pop_back, pop_front and push and pop as implemented for queues. These functions (the pop functions) have a situation where an element can be lost in the presence of an exception (i.e. the element is removed from the collection, but before it is returned an exception occurs (e.g. if the object's constructor can throw).

  By implementing this functionality (read element and pop element) as two separate functions, both can be implemented transactionally.
- [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It is a good design guideline, that if you describe the behavior of a function and need to use the word "and", you have broken SRP and should probably split it in two (i.e. A function that "appends an element at the end *and* returns a reference to it" should probably be written as two functions "add an element at the end" and "return element at the end" - both of which can offer at least weak exception guarantees to client code).

I am not sure if these criteria were applied for the design, but I remember the exception guarantee argument given in a lecture on exception safety.

Comment: Beware that in shared data structures, the sequence of two actions "add an element at the end" and "return element at the end" *is not the same* as the single action "appends an element at the end and returns a reference to that newly added element".

Answer (score 0):

in c++ 11 you can use:

```
m.emplace(val1, val2).first
```

to get a reference to the returned iterator, then:

```
m.emplace(val1, val2).first->first
```

and

```
m.emplace(val1, val2).first->second
```

to access map's k and v

:)