# New emplace_back signature

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

The [signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) of the `emplace_back` method for `std::vector` has been updated to return a reference:

```
template< class... Args >
constexpr reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );
```

While I can find many (older) posts on why this isn't [needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434706/4224575) or even [a bad design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24433524/4224575) I cannot find sources on the rationale for the change.

- Why did this update happen? If the apparent "gives an easier to use interfece" holds, why didn't `push_back` get an update as well?
- Doesn't it complicate exception-safety requirements by complicating the interface?

I'm also searching for the paper that introduced the change, if you could point me to it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: https://wg21.link/p0084

Comment: About *Doesn't it complicate exception-safety requirements by complicating the interface?*.  If an exception is thrown, you are going to leave the scope where the reference would be bound, so there is no problem there.  As far as I can tell it should add no extra anything.

Comment: `push_back` pushes back an already existing object where as `emplace_back` creates a new object and you might want to take a look at it.  In the `push_back` case you can observe/modify the object before pushing it, this is not possible with `emplace_back`

Comment: "_..why didn't push_back get an update as well?..."_ because it was not proposed (no need).

Comment: How to find the paper: I went to wg21.link/index.txt and searched for "Emplace". I saw something that said, "Emplace Return Type"; that was the paper.

Comment: @RichardCritten `push_back` has an rvalue ref version where you can push the result of an expression so one might want to look at that as well. _symmetrically_ `emplace_back` by accepting an rvalue reference can perform an in place move constuction so act upon an "existing" object. What I'm trying to say is that the argument about "looking at the result" can apply to both (as does the argument "don't look at the result:").

Comment: i dont get the point of the "you typically already  have acomplete object in hand" argument for push back because if you want a reference to the object in the vector you still need to call `back()`. I guess it boils down to writing a good proposal and getting it trough. Once its in you can argue either way